# How to access ImageField Object and display it to template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm having trouble accessing the data from db that should have images.
How can I access them and then render them to the template.

```
#models.py
class Pic(models.Model):
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='cover/pdfs', null=True, blank = True)

#forms.py
class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model= Pic
    fields= "__all__"

#views.py
def dash(request):
try:
    _id = request.session['client']['id']
except:
    return redirect("/loginPg")

userBio = Bio.objects.get(userData = User.objects.get(id = request.session['client']['id']))

theUploads = Pic.objects.all()
print("This image object -", theUploads)
#for pic in theUploads:
    #print("MyPc", pic["image"])
content = {
    "title" : userBio.title,
    "qA" : userBio.quoteA,
    "qB" : userBio.quoteB,
    "desc" : userBio.desc,
    "authorA" : userBio.authorA,
    "authorB" : userBio.authorB,
    "pictures" : theUploads
}

return render(request, "GoEnigma/dashboard.html", content)
```

I have heard of Pillow and seen the documentation. I am confused on how that would assist the problem. If there is any ideas on this, I would gladly take them.

Answer (score 2):

In your html, you can iterate over "pictures" like next:

```
{% for picture in pictures %}
  ...
  <img src="{{picture.image.url}}"/>
  ...
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: The object is displaying now. However, I am unable to display the image. I have tried {% for picture%} but I can only get that far.